# Javascript/jQuery Dynamic Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic array using JS/jQuery. The HTML structure is:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="1"/></li>
    <li><img src="2"/></li>
    <li><img src="3"/></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to create a new array of the image sources, so it ends up looking like:

```
var imagesArray = [1, 2, 3];
```

I thought I could use the jQuery `.each()` method...but I keep getting lost. If you can please provide an explanation I would really appreciate it.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  thought correct :) You can use the jQuery .each() method.. as below..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imagesArray =new Array();
  $("ul li img").each(function(){
     imagesArray.push($(this).attr('src'));
  });
  console.log(imagesArray); // this returns ["1", "2", "3"]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var imagesArray = $('img').map(function(){ return this.src; }).get();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pkeBZ/

---

[jQuery's `.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) loops through all the elements, collects whatever is returned from your callback function, and creates a new array out of it.

However, the returned result behaves like an array, but is really an jQuery object (granted, it probably makes no difference in your use case).

If you want to convert a jQuery object into an array, you can use [jQuery's `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: when i add this to my code and alert the results. nothing shows in the alert. maybe I am doing something wrong. Also, can you explain the .map and .get functions. please!

Comment: @mitch - I updated my answer with a demo, and further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet to loop an array in jquery

1) First we declare an arrray

```
var MapAreas = [];
```

2) Now we loop using foreach

```
 $.each(MapAreas, function (index, value) {

         alert(index + ':' + value);   
  }
```

3)  To check if a value is already present in an array use this code snippet

```
if ($.inArray(value, MapAreas) >= 0) {}
```

4) To remove an item from the array use this function

```
RemoveItemFromArray(value, arr) {

       return jQuery.grep(arr, function (elem, index) {

       return elem !== value;

    });

}
```