# how to create dynamic array and adding dynamic values using jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am the beginner in jQuery. how to create the dynamic array and adding dynamic values using jQuery. currently, I'm on this.  I'm getting  this on StackOverflow

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far. It is very important

Comment: Posible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707532/javascript-jquery-dynamic-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it :

Create table

Jquery:

```
$("#my_id_container").html("<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
```

Html:

```
<div id="my_id_container"></div>
```

Add value of this tableau :

```
$("#my_id_container").find('table tbody').append('<tr>My new ligne</tr>');
```